# How to get active button in js when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 buttons in an HTML page. When I click on the `search_track` button I need to get which button (Canada or USA) is active in a javascript function. How can I do this?

```
<div class="buttons-track">
    <button class="btn-track active track-canada" id="canada"></button>
    <button class="btn-track track-usa" id="usa"></button>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12  small-heading">Tracking Number</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 input-small">
    <input type="text" id="trackNum">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 input-small-submit">
    <input type="image" src="img/track.png" id="search_track">
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.btn-track { 
    background: none; 
    border: none; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 98px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.track-canada {  
    background: url(../img/canada.png) no-repeat;     
    background-size: contain;
}
.track-canada.active {  
    background: url(../img/canada-over.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
}
.track-usa {  
    background: url(../img/usa.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain; 
}
.track-usa.active {  
    background: url(../img/usa-over.png) no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```
function search_track() {
    var canada = document.getElementById("canada").value;
    var usa = document.getElementById("usa").value;
}
```

Please help me how to know which button is active in function?

Comment: `$('.active')` or `document.querySelector('.active');`

Comment: @Tushar Thanks , here i am getting object how to find active button id?

Comment: You can use `$('.active').attr('id');` or `document.querySelector('.active').id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the user clicks the third button, the USA or Canada button loses focus. You will always get the `search_track` button as the focus of the event.

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should add attach an event handler to the USA and Canada buttons to set a state variable. Then your `search_track` should have an event handler attached which checks to make sure that the state was sent before working on it. As an example:

```
var country = "Please click on a country";

function setCountry(event) {
    country = this.id;
    return false;
}

function search_track() {
    // do something with country, such as:
    alert(country);
}

document.getElementById("canada").addEventListener("click", setCountry, false);
document.getElementById("usa").addEventListener("click", setCountry, false);
document.getElementById("search_track").addEventListener("click", search_track, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and look for the active class through jQuery, after which you'll get the id with the .attr() function like:

```
var country = $('.active').attr('id');
```

This looks for an element with the class active and stores the ID in the variable country. You can then use this to check which of the countries was selected.